# How can I use my .g4 file created using antlr (parser) in my html document for when a button is pushed?

Tags: java, php, html, parsing, antlr

I created a .g4 file using antlr, in order to parse through a .in file and creates a summary of all of the numbers in the .in file.  I then created a simple html document, which allows numbers to be added to the .in file.  The html file also has another button that I would like to run my parser (.g4) on the .in file when pressed, but I am unaware as to how to use my parser in a .php file or in a .html file.  I believe there is some way to use the parser using java code, and this java code can be used in a php file, but I'm not sure how to link the three.  Any help would be great

Comment: ANTLR should compile your .g4 grammar file to JavaScript or PHP based in your preference and then you can use the generated files in your project.